# Why new line is added in HTML?

Tags: html, css

When I code like this:

```html
<html>

<body>
  <table width="250">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option>AAA</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        a <input type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

There's no newline between 'a' and textbox.

But, when I code like this:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style rel="stylesheet">
    select {
      width: 250px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table width="250">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option>AAA</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        a <input type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

There's new line between 'a' and textbox.

I just added 5 lines.

How can I make it with no new line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your select is the same width as the entire table. You should either make the table wider or your select narrower.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style rel="stylesheet">
    select {
      width: 250px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table width="500">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option>AAA</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        a <input type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all remove two  closing tag  ..
I don't know why your code is not working ...
but if you want no new line between a  and input wrap them inside

```
<p>
```